# Jade template inheritance without Express

Tags: node.js, pug

I would like to use Jade block inheritance but I'm not sure how to do that if I'm not using Express.  According to the Jade doc, I can use block inheritance in Express by simply adding `app.set('view options', { layout: false });`.  How can I achieve this without Express?

https://github.com/visionmedia/jade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need Express at all to use Jade's [Template inheritance](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#template-inheritance); you only need Jade:

```
// app.js
var jade = require('jade');

var options = { pretty: true, locals: {} };

jade.renderFile(__dirname + '/home.jade', options, function (err, html) {
    console.log(html);
});
```

```
// home.jade
extends core

block body
  h1 Home
```

```
// core.jade
doctype html
html
  head
    meta(charset='utf-8')
    title Foo
  body
    block body
```

Another example can be found in the repository:

- [`examples/extend.js`](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/blob/master/examples/extend.js)
- [`examples/extend.jade`](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/blob/master/examples/extend.jade)
- [`examples/extend-layout.jade`](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/blob/master/examples/extend-layout.jade).

The reason the Jade docs mention setting the `'view options'` for Express 2.x is because Express' own (and [now defunct](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-2.x-to-3.x) in 3.x) layouts are a competing feature that should be disabled to prevent conflicts when using Jade's inheritance.